# TypeError: a.then is not a function while compiling in production

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vite

I'm trying to compile my vue app in production with `npm run build` (which is vite build).

After that I try to serve my app on my server with the /dist folder and everything seems to be working perfectly, I'm able to send fetch request, click on various links etc.

Unfortunately, after logging in and when I should be redirected, I'm getting the error

> TypeError: a.then is not a function while compiling in production

and

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: a.then is not a function"

Everything just works perfectly fine while I'm in dev mode, it's just not working in production.

It seems to be linked to the router

This is the code for my Router :

```js
const state = reactive({
    token: localStorage.getItem("token"),
    userAdmin: false,
    userRestaurateur: false,
    userDeliverer: false
});

if (state.token) {
    const user = JSON.parse(atob(state.token.split('.')[1]))
    state.userAdmin = Object.values(user.roles).includes('ROLE_ADMIN');
    state.userRestaurateur = Object.values(user.roles).includes('ROLE_RESTAURANT');
    state.userDeliverer = Object.values(user.roles).includes('ROLE_DELIVERER');
}

const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory('/'),
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'home',
            component: function () {
                if (state.token && state.userAdmin) {
                    return Users
                } else if (state.token && state.userRestaurateur) {
                    return HomeRestaurateur
                }else if (state.token && state.userDeliverer) {
                    return Commands
                }else {
                    return Home
                }
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/login",
            name: "login",
            component: Login,
        },
        {
            path: "/forgot-password",
            name: "forgot_password",
            component: ForgotPassword,
        },
        {
            path: "/reset-password/:token",
            name: "reset_password_token",
            component: ResetPassword,
        },
        {
            path: "/register",
            name: "register",
            component: Register,
        },
        {
            path: "/profile",
            name: "editProfile",
            component: editProfile,
        },
        {
            path: "/Restaurant/:id/Menu",
            name: "Meals",
            component: Meals,
        },
        {
            path: "/admin/users",
            name: "admin_users",
            component: function () {
                if (state.userAdmin) {
                    return Users
                } else {
                    return Error403
                }
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/admin/restaurants",
            name: "admin_restaurants",
            component: function () {
                if (state.userAdmin) {
                    return Restaurants
                } else {
                    return Error403
                }
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/admin/restaurants_request",
            name: "admin_restaurants_request",
            component: function () {
                if (state.userAdmin) {
                    return RestaurantsRequest
                } else {
                    return Error403
                }
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/restaurants/new",
            name: "create_restaurants",
            component: CreateRestaurant,
        },
        {
            path: "/admin/reports",
            name: "admin_reports",
            component: function () {
                if (state.userAdmin) {
                    return Reports
                } else {
                    return Error403
                }
            }
        },
        {
            path: "/orders",
            name: "orders",
            component: Commands,
        },
        {
            path: "/:pathMatch(.*)*",
            name: "not_found",
            component: Error404,
        }
    ],
});
```

I tried checking if other methods were working correctly, tried to change server, nothing just seems to work.

Comment: Did you check if import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL is available for it in production?

Comment: I think so, just edited my post because I think it's linked to my router, apparently it could be linked more precisely to "component :"

Comment: There is no `a` variable in your snippet. More info would help. Please provide full stack trace or runnable code.

Comment: Disable minification if you can't debug minified code, you can click on stack trace and check the exact location. Currently only you can do that, there's no `then` in the code you posted, see https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Try doing this, put up some console logs during the login process and also log the import.meta.env.VITE_API_URL. This would give better information to debug even in production.

Comment: The answer was that you can't pass a function to the component line, I had to do component: Home instead of passing a function

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was having the same problem. My local build was working fine, but after building for production and deploying to my server, I was getting a similar error.

My console error was

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: i.then is not a function"
```

The stacktrace pointed to vue-router. I tried many things until I saw your comment. In my routes, I had functions for the components like:

```
  {
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'Profile',
    component: () => Profile, //this was the problem
  },
```

I changed it to:

```
  {
    path: '/profile',
    name: 'Profile',
    component: Profile, //this was the fix
  },
```

and now it is working!